# Where can I find example files using M2Doc for Capella 6.0.0?

Tags: m2doc

I have not been able to find any example file for use of M2Doc within Capella 6.0.0. The normal example is the Flight entertainment system. Is there still an example available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [extension page for Capella](https://www.m2doc.org/capella/) that explain how to install and use the extensions with Capella. At the bottom of the page you also have a link to both templates provided with the IFE example as well as the generated document.

Comment: I did see the links, but the tutorial instructions did not work correctly. I realized my installation got corrupted and I did a re-install of Capella and M2Doc and now everything is working as per the tutorial (at least up to getting the example loaded) Thanks for the answer.